# Setting background color and background image in CSS

Tags: css

I have a problem with setting a background image over my background color: Here is my example so that you can see what I mean: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmvXA/9/)

Now here is the functional CSS part:

```css
#tancan{
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    background-image: url('http://lamininbeauty.co.za/images/products/tancan2.jpg');
}
```

As you can see in the JSFiddle, the background image repeats. If I use no-repeat as a property, the image disappears.

Also, I want the background image to float to the right, and should the image be bigger than the containing div, how to I make it fit proportionally? - Like you would make an image tag `<img/>` fit by using `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`?

I don't want to use an HTML image tag, it would be much easier but there are several reasons I do not want to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/vmvXA/17/

```css
#tancan {
    background: #ebebeb url('http://lamininbeauty.co.za/images/products/tancan2.jpg') no-repeat top right;
}
```

and to make the background image not exceed its parent container you can use `background-size: contain` - http://jsfiddle.net/vmvXA/22/

Comment: awesome man, thank you. Two questions though, what if the image is larger than the div dimensions(try using tancan.jpg instead of tancan2.jpg to see what I mean...)How do I center it? Also, is this style you used: background: #color url(); compatible with older browsers such as IE7 and 8?

Comment: yes, the CSS shortcuts backward compatible till IE4 and Netscape Navigator :) Also updated the answer with `background-size: contain`

Answer (score 2):

You can't just add `no-repeat` to `background-image`, because `background-image` is a specific property that only refers to the image itself. If you want to add it all in one declaration, then set `background`:

```
background: url('http://lamininbeauty.co.za/images/products/tancan2.jpg') #ebebeb no-repeat top right;
```

or keep it all separate, up to you:

```
background-color: #ebebeb;
background-image: url('http://lamininbeauty.co.za/images/products/tancan2.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:top right;
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: You can scale the background, mate. :) With background-size. Check my answer for more insight. :D

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/transparent/vmvXA/24/).

```
    background:#ebebeb url('http://lamininbeauty.co.za/images/products/tancan2.jpg') no-repeat right top;
```

To make the code shorter, it is possible to specify all the settings in one single property. This is called a 'shorthand property'.

To make all pictures fit inside it's parent add the style property `background-size:contain;`.

Updated the fiddle.

Comment: thanks mate. Is this shorthand supported by older browsers such as IE7 and 8?